# Why is one div positioning itself higher and underneath another div?

Tags: html, css

From top down, I have a wrapper div, a hdr div, a slider-container div, and a body-container div.  It seems to be a intermittent issue because when I refresh the screen the problem fixes itself.  The body-container div sliding underneath the slider container div.  The slider is still visible on top, but it is covering up all the text in the body container, all the way down to just aboove the "Safety and Quality Assurance."  The url is [http://infinitywellcontrol.com/][1]

```
#wrapper {
background:  #fae7ce; 
width: 100%;    
margin-left: auto;  
margin-right: auto;  }

#hdr  {
height:  100px;
width:  100%;
margin:  0 auto;
padding:  0px; }

#slider-container  {
width:  100%; 
height:  auto;
background:  #484848; 
border-top:  1px solid #777777; 
border-bottom:  1px solid #777777;  }

#body-container {
width: 1050px; 
color: #484848; 
line-height:  150%;
margin: 45px auto 150px auto;  
background:  #fae7ce;  
display:  table;  }


<div id="hdr">
   <div id="hdr-content">
        <div id="hdr-left">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" 
width="510" height="90" alt="frac valve rental and repair services"></a> 
        </div>
        <div id="hdr-right"> 
          <div id="hdr-nav">
             <div style="position:  relative; z-index:  999;">
                 <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                     <ul>
                       <li><a href="repairs.html">Repairs</a></li>
                       <li><a href="rentals.html">Rentals</a></li>
                       <li><a href="maintenance.html">Maintenance</a></li>
                       <li><a href="weld-repairs.html">Weld Repairs</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li>
             <li><a href="quality-assurance.html">Quality Assurance</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
                         </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

      </div>
</div>

<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="fade">
       <img src="images/frac-valve-service1.jpg" width="1920" 
height="auto" alt="frac valve repair service south texas">
       <img src="images/frac-valve-service2.jpg" width="1920" height="auto" alt="frac valve repair service corpus christi">
       <img src="images/frac-valve-service3.jpg" width="1920" height="auto" alt="frac valve repair service orange grove">
       <img src="images/frac-valve-service4.jpg" width="1920" height="auto" alt="frac valve repair service oil and petroleum industry">
    </div>
 </div>


<div id="body-container">
        ........
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the #slider-container (it has 2px height).

You have 2 choices:

1) Add height to #slider-container (for example 500px)

2) Add padding-top: 500px to #body-container (better option in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

All the elements inside the element `#fade` have their CSS property `position` set to `absolute`. Check the MDN definition:

> **absolute**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

That means that the `height: auto` you set into the element `#slider-container` will not work as intended, because the inner elements don't have a fixed height by themselves, which mean that they will not expand the container.

For additional information, check the MDN page about the property [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height). The initial value of the property is `auto`, so you can save some code by not adding it to every element.

Since we know that every image inside your carousel have a fixed height of **500px**, we can fix the problem with a single property:

```
#slider-container {height: 500px}
```